# How to animate element when you scroll down and then up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with animation, when you start scrolling down the picture going with you until offset().top = 960px but when you scroll up this picture have to go with you to the top - and this is a problem then i don't know how to return it to the top. Here is my site, this animation on the top

```
//scroll cicada
    var x = true;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var item = $("#cicada").offset().top;
        var place = $("#circles").offset().top;
        if (item >= 950 && x) {
            $("#cicada").css("position", "absolute");
            $("#cicada").css("top", "950px");
            x = false;
        } else if (item <= 950 && !x) {
            $("#cicada").css("top", "160px");
            x = true;
        }
    });
```

css:

```
.cicada {
        width: 340px;
        height: 380px;
        background: url("../includes/images/main-item-min.png") no-repeat center center;
        background-size: contain;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 5;
        top: 160px;
        right: 59%;
        z-index: 8888;
    }
```

Comment: On scroll up, Your menu bar shows up again. But, it should not, right?

Comment: when the animation is on 950 the picture is fixed, but when you scroll up it start moving again with to the top http://99.sysale.ua/

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, you should make your `header` visible only, when you are at top of your scroll i.e. when `currentTop` is 0.

```
var currentTop = $(window).scrollTop();
   if (currentTop == 0) {
      $("header").css("display", "block");
   } else {
      $("header").css("display", "none");
      if ($('.menu').hasClass("change")) {
        $('.menu').removeClass("change");
      }
   }
```

I hope, It will help.

Comment: no, it's not a header it's a div element - when you scroll up at first you have to scroll to some point and this div element stays there but when you scroll up you pick this div up and drag to the top

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. But, you should only make your div visible when you are at top of the page. But, in your code it will make your div visible every time your scroll up, even if you scroll up by just 1 pixel.

Comment: it has to be always visible, only change a place on the web site http://99.sysale.ua/

Comment: @DimaVleskov I am not getting you actually. Do you want your header to be always visible or you want it to hide when you scroll down?